# Unicode sql query in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, unicode, cx-oracle

i have the following:

```
ora_wet = oracle_connection()
cursor = ora_wet.cursor()
sqlQuery = u"SELECT * FROM web_cities WHERE cty_name = 'София'"
cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
sqlResult = cursor.fetchone()
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expecting None or a string on line 18 which is the cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
```

If I make the query non-unicode (without the u) it goes through but it returns nothing

edit: in reply to first comment:

NLS_LANGUAGE is BULGARIAN,

NLS_CHARACTERSET is CL8MSWIN1251

language is Python...

yes there is a record with cty_name = 'София'

connection is just:

```
def oracle_connection():
    return cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@server')

ora_wet = oracle_connection()
```

Comment: Is there a city named 'София' in the database? What is the database characterset? What programming language is this? How is the connection to the database made? What are the NLS_LANG settings?

Comment: I think you can't apply the unicode transform to the sqlQuery string and must apply it to only the search value (passed as a bind variable).

Comment: This actually did work. Thanks a lot. If you post it as a an answer I can accept it.